# How to enter spaces in a for loop in c language using conditions

Tags: c

The number of spaces in each line will change as per the number that is given in the for loop. So if the number changes to 2 as per the for loop, it will have 2 spaces in that line and the number will go on increasing in every line in an ascendinfg order.

Comment: Could you provide an example of what you're looking to do and what you've tried?

Comment: Is it a question or answer? As you are providing the solution in the question

Comment: Try to make your question more clear pls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int i, j;

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
  for(j = 0; j < i; j++) printf(" ");
  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int i,j;
for (i=1; i<5; i++){
    for (j=1; j<=i; j++){ // it will print i spaces whenever i increases. 
        printf(" ");
    }
}
```